# SCP client for MAC OS Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I have just upgraded to Mac OS Lion and I have a problem with Fugu application that I used to use on Snow Leopard, I can't run it on Lion now.

Do you know how a patch for running it on Lion or have you alternative applications which does the same things ?

I know there is the Terminal (scp localPath login@ip:distantPath) to copy files but it's easier to do this job with a SCP client if you are looking for the file you want to transfer among all directories.

Comment: Off topic - should be moved to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fugu works for me on Lion. Perhaps you should just download a newer version, or give details on the error you get.

If you don't mind spending money on it, [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) is a great alternative (that is, if you're comfortable with SFTP).

Anyway, this question doesn't really belong here.

Answer (score 0):

I use Interarchy, not that expensive and great to work with.

For Fugu, there is a preview release that works on Lion.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fugussh/files/