# Adding user/pass to one webpage

Tags: passwords

I am looking to add a username and password to one specific webpage I shall be creating. I have seen many guides but most either 'lock' the whole site or, alternatively, are that simple that the user and pass can be easily seen in the source.

So I need something secure that locks just one page and is also not too complex (as I would probably get lost..)

It's a html site and I just need one login for all, not different ones for different people.

Comment: Set it in your web server. Putting the password in the html is probably the worst idea.

Comment: Yes, i intend to set it in the web server but not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: What is the web server you are using? If Apache then the easiest (not really safe though) is Basic Authentication: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Comment: I found this guide which seems easy enough however when trying to upload the .htpasswd.txt file via filezilla, keep getting 'Critical transfer error'. Is this a setting in filezilla?

Comment: It might be... if this is a linux/unix server (probably it is) try WinSCP

Comment: any alternative to WinSCP for mac?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688647/scp-client-for-mac-os-lion

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: Ok, pretty much sorted according to the tutorial (its quite easy to do) and now get popup password prompt however when entering details, I just got this error http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-21%20at%2012.40.16.png and keep getting it now whenever I try to open the page

Comment: Incidentally, I got that other ftp client but the clients ftp log in is no longer working so using the remembered details from filezilla therefore rather than uploading the .htpasswrd file to outside the root, i had to upload to the root and rename as suggested on the guide

Comment: i HAVE AuthUserFile /public_html/.htxuymwp, the example suggests it should look like /home/username/public_html/.htxuymwp but Im not sure what this path could be?

Comment: /public/html/.htxuymwp is fine

Comment: Now the error is probably caused by misconfiguration, you should check the server logs.

Comment: Can I check server logs without having access to any sort of cpanel? this is a clients website so have ftp access only. I have never done this type of password access before hence the questions that may be obvious to most!

Comment: If you can upload files, you can probably read the logs too. Also cPanel should have an "Error logs" or something like that.

Comment: Can't see any error logs in the ftp and have no access to cpanel. I think I'll look for an easier option temporarily then get full access to cpanel etc. Thanks for the help